# Wrapping object issues

Tags: shrinkwrap, solidify-modifier

I'm a debutant in blender and I got some issues while working on the donut tutorial. I give a shape to my donut at the start before coming back to modify it a way later. Now I'm trying to wrap my icing around the donut as it was previously (image 1)
I used shrinkwrap modifier on the icing and added a solidify. Then it gave me this kind of jagged form (image 2)
Also, I lost a lot of the icing thickness (image 3)
I figured I could take it back by increasing the solidify's thickness but I dont know how to do it the right way (image 4 and 5)

How can I wrap my icing around the donut properly ? Thanks.

https://1drv.ms/f/s!AoQ_BDPUpElgnD3xYiJFRIypFCLb?e=PqvfuR (here's the images)

Comment: please embed your images directly into the post

Comment: Please show the images and share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

#1 is to make sure you have enough subdivisions which will make it smooth. #2 and probably more important is to do the shrink-wrap BEFORE the solidify which should solve the jaggedness

Comment: This is what I did. The more I increase the thickness, the more the object is getting weird (Image 6)

https://1drv.ms/f/s!AoQ_BDPUpElgnD3xYiJFRIypFCLb?e=PqvfuR